# Not able to create site-package inside /usr/lib/Python2.7 it shows "Operation not permitted"

Tags: python-2.7, thrift, macos-mojave

I was trying to install thrift(0.11.0) over my system(macOs 10.14.5).For which I downloaded and extracted tar file. Then I ran following commands :

```
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

But **make install** throwed the following error  :

```
error: could not create '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages': Operation not permitted
```

then I also tried manually creating site-package inside /usr/lib/python2.7 but still the error message was same.
I have also tried **sudo** while running **make install** but it didn't helped much.

Comment: Consider asking that on the mailing list.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you reach anything?

Answer (score 1):

1.open thrift's subfolder lib/py/ and modify the Makefile as follow:

PY_PREFIX=/usr

change to

PY_PREFIX = /Users/amy/python

2.sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem trying to install thrift on Mac OS.

I found a separate guide for installing thrift on Mac OS, I tried it and it finally worked successfully:

1- Download the boost library from [boost.org](http://www.boost.org/) untar compile with

```
./bootstrap.sh
sudo ./b2 threading=multi address-model=64 variant=release stage install
```

2- Download [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent), untar and compile with

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local 
make
sudo make install
```

3- Download the latest version of [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/download), untar and compile with

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --with-boost=/usr/local --with-libevent=/usr/local
```

Try it and let me know your results.

*Reference: [Apache Thrift - OS X Install](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/os_x)*